# Instagram API returning error when requesting access_token on Windows Phone

Tags: oauth, instagram

I've been trying to integrate the Instagram API in my app, but am stuck with the authentication. I had it working completely fine when I was just using the implicit flow version which gave me the access_token as part of the URI fragment.
However, now I'm changing to the server-side flow, in which I receive a code after the user logs in. I then post this code to the access token URL, which will then give me the access_token as well as certain information about the user, such as their username and profile picture link.

I am using the InstaSharp library, modifying the source code.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(config.OAuthUri + "access_token/", UriKind.Absolute) };
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress);

        request.AddParameter("client_secret", config.ClientSecret);
        request.AddParameter("client_id", config.ClientId);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", config.RedirectUri);
        request.AddParameter("code", code);

        return client.ExecuteAsync<OAuthResponse>(request);
```

After creating my request, it is formatted as so:
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/?client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://instagram.com &code={CODE}', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers: { }}
(I inserted the space between the redirect_uri and code because it wouldn't let me post the question otherwise)

Everything appears normal in the address, but I always receive an error in the retuned json file:

"{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must provide a client_id"}"

I have no clue what is causing this error. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Elliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of InstaSharp? Fork it [here](https://github.com/burkeholland/InstaSharp). You can check the README.md there although it's a bit outdated and you need to tweak some config. Here's how you can do it with the latest version that is in github:

```
// create the configuration in a place where it's more appropriate in your app
InstaSharpConfig = new InstagramConfig(
    apiURI, oauthURI, clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri);

// then here's a sample method you can have to initiate auth 
// and catch the redirect from Instagram
public ActionResult instagramauth(string code)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
    {
        var scopes = new List<InstaSharp.Auth.Scope>();
        scopes.Add(InstaSharp.Auth.Scope.likes);
        var link = InstaSharp.Auth.AuthLink(
            oauthURI, clientId, redirectUri, scopes);
        // where:
        // oauthURI is https://api.instagram.com/oauth
        // clientId is in your Instagram account
        // redirectUri is the one you set in your Instagram account; 
        // for ex: http://yourdomain.com/instagramauth

        return Redirect(link);
    }

    // add this code to the auth object
    var auth = new InstaSharp.Auth(InstaSharpConfig);

    // now we have to call back to instagram and include the code they gave us
    // along with our client secret
    var oauthResponse = auth.RequestToken(code);

    // save oauthResponse in session or database, whatever suits your case

    // oauthResponse contains the field Access_Token (self-explanatory), 
    // and "User" that'll give you the user's full name, id, 
    // profile pic and username


    return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");
}
```

Take note that you can split up the "instagramauth" method. Did it that way for brevity.